# Adding hours to new Date().toLocaleTimeString

Tags: javascript, time

Tried searching how to add or modify time of .toLocaleTimeString in JS as that one didn't work with the calc I used to begin with. I have an output that gives me a number of hours (positive or negative) away from the users location, and I want that to be added to their actual time.

This is what I want to maniuplate and add/remove hours based on an output of say, -7 (as in "7 hours west") or 7 (as in "7 hours east"):

```
var endTime = new Date(unixUserTime*1000);

endTime.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12: true});
```

What I tried before:

```
var endTime = new Date(unixUserTime*1000);
// Hours part from the timestamp
var hours = Math.floor(endTime.getHours() + 3);
// Minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = "0" + endTime.getMinutes();
// Seconds part from the timestamp
var seconds = "0" + endTime.getSeconds();
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
formattedTime.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12: true}); //This throws an error
```

And I also tried converting to begin with, like this:

```
var endTime = new Date(unixUserTime*1000).toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit', hour12: true}); //This throws an error;
// Hours part from the timestamp
var hours = Math.floor(endTime.getHours() + 3);
// Minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = "0" + endTime.getMinutes();
// Seconds part from the timestamp
var seconds = "0" + endTime.getSeconds();
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
formattedTime;
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/)

You can do it easily with it without messing up with locales:

```
moment(date).add(7, 'hours')
// for offsets
moment(date).utcOffset(60)
moment(date).utcOffset('+0100')
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it when I'm back to it, but I'd really want to learn to do it myself to begin with as it better helps me understand how to work with JS fundementally.